# How to read League Of Legends ingame chat in Java?

Tags: java, logging, chat

I would like to read the League Of Legends chat during a match and log it all to a file.
Though I do not have the slightest idea how to actually connect to the server and read the chat.

Does anyone have a link or an idea how to accomplish this?

Regards

Comment: AFAIK you can't really access them, and unless there is some API, I would say no...
[source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3405920)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to do some reverse-engineering, since the game's source code is not available. This is likely illegal based on your local laws.

You'll need to use a tool such as Wireshark to figure out how packets are encoded and what is being sent. You'll likely see text strings some of the time, cluing you in to what is happening. By sorting packets and seeing their frequency when doing certain actions, you may be able to deduce what packets must be sent for authentication, keepalive, and chat, and what packets must be listened for.

You can then build a Java implementation using `Socket` or `DatagramSocket` for TCP or UDP, respectively, depending on what the original uses. This is quite a bit of work, however, a a major (and did I say possibly illegal?) undertaking. Even with games where the source is available, redeveloping arcane network protocols is difficult and due to lack of information, will require quite a bit of hardwiring (using byte arrays often) for parts of packets.

Just so you're aware, this is probably illegal and I'm fairly certain they'll close your account for this.

<sub>The author of this post, Stack Exchange (inc), Stack Overflow, any affiliated parties, or organizations, will **not** be held liable for any legal consequences you may face. You may choose to do this at *your own risk*</sub>

Edit: You could try to use `Robot` and simple OCR or text extraction of some sort. It's still a somewhat questionable activity from the standpoint of game administrators and not too reliable.